# Can composer generate the `composer.lock` without actually download the packages?

Tags: php, composer-php

It does exist a command to generate the `composer.lock` from a `composer.json`?

Something similar ruby's `bundler` : `$ bundle lock`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Seems like a weird requirement.

Comment: I think `composer update --lock` does this. "--lock: Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date." or perhaps [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/754#issuecomment-6043855)

Comment: @Sevvlor I don't have deps installed at first, and running `update --lock` it installs them..

Comment: I actually think that this is not possible without installing or updating. [Which is probably due to it's purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44412385/1604068)

Comment: @ciaoben What's wrong with installing them first?

Comment: @Sevvlor that last comment seems like the right answer to the question. Make it a real answer.

Comment: I actually think this would be very useful.

In my scenario I need to update the version of a dependency in 6 applications. Because this feature is not available I have to checkout each application and install ALL the dependencies (70,000 files) just to get the lock file updated.
Would be great to skip the copying of 70,000 files.

Comment: Please add some clarification to your question - what would be wrong in running `composer install` to generate the file?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

### If you do not have a `composer.lock`

The answer is "no", you have to generate the lock file using:

```
composer install
```

> Installing Without composer.lock
>
> If you have never run the command before and there is also **no composer.lock file present**, Composer simply resolves all dependencies listed in your composer.json file and **downloads the latest version** of their files into the vendor directory in your project.

Source: [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-without-composer-lock)

**NB Potential Issue:** Without the lock file Composer will use the latest version of the dependencies.

### If you already have a `composer.lock`

If you already have a `composer.lock` and Composer is complaining about it being out of sync, you'll see this warning:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

To fix this you can update the lock file itself, without updating the dependencies. This will only update the `content-hash` in the lock file:

```
composer update --lock
```

From the Composer manual:

> --lock Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date.

Comment: So can I somehow create a dummy `composer.lock` file and then the the `composer update --lock` to get effectivery the same lock file as with `composer install`?

Comment: From what I can see in [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) the only way to generate a composer.lock is by running composer install. It would be nice if `--dry-run` or a similar flag wrote the lock file if it is missing.

Comment: created an issue for it directly in the composer repo - https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8551

Comment: @mvorisek if I could give you kudos or a bounty I would, your suggestion will be included in Composer 2.0!

Comment: just noting `composer update --lock` will also update other parts of the lock file to match `composer.json` not only the hash.

Comment: And what is the command for updating the lock file for Composer v2? I do not want to update any package just the lock file to match checksum and other parts.

Answer (score 33):

Writing lock file `composer.lock` without download packages:

```
composer update --no-install
```

> **--no-install:** Does not run the install step after updating the composer.lock file.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u-upgrade

(originally reported against Composer version 2.2.5)